# java.lang.ClassCastException compile time check could have been handled better way

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have two classes parent and child, clascastexception occurs in runtime
for the below code given.

From the below code its obvious that there will be classcastexception.
I am thinking that java could have handled in betterway so that in the below case it could have given compile time error.

I is there any other reason that java is not giving error during compile time.
Just want to know if anything i am missing.

```
public class ClassCastExcp {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Child chd = (Child) new Parent(); //it will force you to cast and gives classcastexception in runtime
    }

}

class Parent{
}

class Child extends Parent{
}
```

Comment: `Parent` doesn't extend `Child`. That's why there is a class cast exception.

Comment: **Why** did you add the *cast*? The compiler did give you an error. The cast is you saying I know better. `Parent chd = new Child();` is a correct example of using inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, but why compiler should save me, where its obvious run time error.

Comment: Because it's easier to detect error at compile time than at run time, and also because run time errors can damage data, but not compile time errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you wrote, I take it that you fully understand why you get the runtime exception.  (If not, see the other answers.)

> Is there any reason that java is not giving error during compile time. Just want to know if anything I am missing.

It is not giving a compilation error because the code is legal Java according to the JLS.  (See @ajb's answer for more details, but the real explanation is in the JLS itself.)   A compliant Java compiler is required to accept this ... at least in "compliant" mode.

Now, a Java compiler *is allowed to* report a warning for something like this, and it is also allowed to escalate warnings to errors.  However:

- This particular example is pretty unlikely in real code.  Compiler writers typically generally don't go to the bother of implementing warnings for mistakes that occur rarely.
- Anyone who implemented a Java compiler that treated this kind of thing an error *by default* would get a lot of flak from users who have to deal with code written by other people / organizations.

Comment: Child chd = new someRandomObject(); here the error whould be Type mismatch: cannot convert from someRandomObject to Child. The same way compiler will have metadata and could have handled in the above case. I am thinking in this way.

Comment: Obviously.  That is a different case.  And the JLS requires a cast there.  It is only when the object is created in the same method as the cast where a compiler could easily detect the mistake that the cast **cannot** work.  That is an *edge case*.  I have already explained why the compiler doesn't implement this.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence in [JLS 15.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.3) is important:

> In other words, the value of an expression whose type is T is always
>   suitable for assignment to a variable of type T.

This means that if an expression has class type `T`, then at run time, the actual value could be any type that could be assigned to a variable of type `T`, i.e. `T` or any subclass.

The language rules are written based on this.  Thus, if you say

```
(T2)expression
```

where the expression has type `T`, the above sentence means that the compiler can only assume that at runtime, the expression can have type `T` or some subclass.  The cast is legal if there's any possibility that the expression could be cast to `T2`.  In your case, since some of the subclasses of `Parent` could be cast to `Child`, then it's legal.

The case of `new Parent()` might be a special case; now we know that the expression must have type `Parent` and *cannot* be of a subclass type.  But for Java to make this illegal, the rules would have to be rewritten (language specifications depend on having rules spelled out precisely, so that programs are portable between compilers; compilers aren't really allowed to use "common sense").  The JLS would have to invent the concept of an expression with an "exact type", or something like that, and then a lot of other rules would need to be changed to deal with this sort of expression.  A lot of work would be required to add this kind of rule in several places and verify that everything in the language rules is still consistent; and all that work would only affect pathological cases such as your original post that never occur in practice.  So it definitely wouldn't be worth it for Java to make this illegal.

Comment: Yeah as per JLS java is behaving correctly. As you told "for Java to make this illegal, the rules would have to be rewritten". Here all we got to know something good from this discussion. Later java may apply it. :)

Comment: If, in a future version of Java, there's some _other_ good reason for the rules to be aware of an expression with an "exact type", then this might become illegal.  I wouldn't rule it out.  Java 8 already had to make some major changes to add lambdas and method references; now you have expressions that don't have types on their own, or at least not the usual kind of type.  Who knows what new feature in Java 11 might require a similar sort of major change.

Comment: I >>would<< rule it out.  It would be a breaking change.  They don't make breaking changes unless there is an overwhelming reason to do that.  (I don't think there were any changes in Java 8 that made illegal code that was previously legal.)

Comment: @StephenC OK, valid point, although making something illegal that can't possibly work anyway is a "breaking" change only in a narrow technical sense.  Re your parenthesized statement: I've seen someone claim that Java 8 did break his code, but he never provided details when I asked, and I don't know whether the breakage was making something illegal.  I think that adding any method to an existing class could potentially make legal code illegal (by making something ambiguous) if `import static` with a wildcard is used a lot.

Comment: I am talking about breaking at the language level; i.e. causing a program that previously compiled correctly to no longer compile.  I will accept that you can get "new" compilation errors due to wildcard imports (not just static) and I'm excluding that.  (The problem there is a library incompatibility not a linguistic incompatibility.  And it is largely the programmer's own fault .... IMO.  It is well known / widely accepted that wildcard imports are fragile.)

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, please see below snippet

```
 Object x = new Integer(0);
 System.out.println((String)x);
```

Now, println() method expects `String` so we type cast `x` which is type of `Object` to `String`. But, at the runtime `Object x` get instance of `Integer`. Since, `Integer` can not be casted to `String`. It will throw `ClassCastException` exception at runtime.

Now, coming back to your question, it is an example of down casting. You can not store parent instance to child. Please refer link commented by @Axel in your post.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: no, he did not ask why there was a class cast exception.

Answer (score -1):

It will not throw  `classcastexception` if  up-casting of the object is done first then down-casting.

```
Parent p1=new Child();    
Child chd = (Child) p1; // it will not throw classcastexception
```

Comment: This seems to be an answer to a question that wasn't asked.